# Подсчет ссылок в C++

Tags: c++, память, counter

Как реализовать подсчет ссылок при создании собственного класса C++?

То есть нужен счетчик, который хранил бы количество ссылок, ссылающихся на объект. Если этот счетчик равен нулю, то объект необходимо удалить. Хочется разобраться в этом, но не имею ни малейшей мысли как это реализовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простейший вариант - примерно так (это набросок, не более того):

```
class CountedPtr
{
    ...
        Type1 p1;  // Данные
        Type2 p2;  // Данные
        .... 
        int  * cnt;  // Счетчик
```

В конструкторе - помимо прочего -

```
cnt = new int(1);
```

В копирующем конструкторе - `cnt` копируется и увеличивается на 1. Соответственно обрабатывается присваивание (проще всего его реализовать через идиому обмена с копией). В деструкторе - что-то типа

```
if (--*cnt == 0) { delete ptr; delete cnt; }
```

Для начала (и понимания азов) хватит?

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть ответ того, кто минусует - у вас наверняка куда более верное представление о происходящем, так поделитесь!

Comment: такие люди сидят в тени обычно, я подниму

Comment: Я вот тоже поставил минус. Прежде всего потому, что этот ответ не отвечает на вопрос - счетчик-то будет отдельно от экземпляра класса. Тут скорее простейший вариант `shared_ptr`

Comment: Да, я примерно так это себе и представлял, но тут возникала проблема. Допустим, мы все это реализовали, и есть следующий код:

 `CounterPtr ptr1 = *something*; 

  CounterPtr ptr2 = ptr1;
`

После удаления объекта `ptr2`, необходимо, чтобы счетчик ссылок объекта `ptr1` уменьшался на единицу. Как реализовать этот момент? Видимо, идиома обмена с копией, как раз об этом? Спасибо.

Comment: @Иван Так а вам все-таки нужен внешний счетчик или счетчик для своего класса?

Comment: @VTT счетчик для своего класса, но чтобы не надо было в `main` писать ничего лишнего, чтобы реализация этого счетчика была скрыта, как, например, в STL, где подсчет используется, но никаких `shared_ptr` и прочего мы явно не вызываем

Comment: @VTT я считаю что минус ставить нужно только в самом крайнем случае, если случай так себе лучше вообще ничего не ставить.

Comment: @Иван Но ведь приведенный в этом ответе код является по сути тем же `shared_ptr`. Счетчик существует в явном виде и не привязан к классу. Непонятно, о подсчете чего в STL вы говорите. Единственное, что мне приходит на ум в этой связи - строки с внутренний подсчетом ссылок и copy on write, но эта реализация стала конформной и ее заменили на более традиционную.

Comment: @VTT о подсчете ссылок в, например, `string` писал Мейерс в "Эффективном использовании STL". А я как раз для изучения пытаюсь написать класс `string`

Comment: @Иван Вот это поворот... Надо было это сразу указать в вопросе, а то так получается, что все ответы тут вообще не в тему (но не далеко от нее).

Comment: @VTT **Данные** больше не являются членом класса? Если бы я написал `int i;`, то вам бы стало понятнее?

Comment: @Иван Ну вот и пишите. Добавьте `char * ptr` - указатель на строку, в чем проблема? Или я где-то написал, что в конструкторе **больше нельзя ничего делать**? Я дал *набросок* того, как это делать. Или вы ждете готовый код - для класса, о котором вы забыли рассказать?

Comment: @Harry Я думал, что ОПу надо было держать счетчик как часть *целевого* класса, то бишь как часть `Type`. А написать `int i` в данном случае нельзя, иначе разные экземпляры `CountedPtr`, владеющие одним и тем же экземпляром объекта `Type`, будут иметь разные счетчики.

Comment: @VTT *Целевой класс* в моем примере - `CountedPtr`. Так, как я переписал - вас больше устраивает? Идиому Pimpl, например, как я понимаю. вы тоже не считаете как реализацию целевого класса?

Comment: До этого у вас был скорее реализация `shared_ptr`, а теперь непонятно что. Если данные хранятся непосредственно в каждом экземпляре класса, то непонятно, за разделение владения чем отвечает счетчик ссылок.

Comment: @VTT Задолбали. Проще удалить, чем с вами спорить. Восстановите свой ответ, пожалуйста - а я свой удалю. Пока он принят - я это сделать, увы, не могу.

Answer (score 3):

Все уже реализовано: используйте [`std::shared_ptr`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Можно с примерами? Я понимаю, как использовать `shared_ptr` в функции `main`, по типу:  `shared_ptr<int> a (new int(10));
 shared_ptr<int> b (new int(0));
  b = a;` Но не понимаю, как это встроить в класс. И можно ли его использовать с массивами, например `char[]`? Должен ли подсчет реализовываться в конструкторе? Или как вообще, слабо понимаю.

Comment: А в чем проблема встраивания в класс?

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже оставлю здесь пример своей псевдореализации умного указателя, так как вопрос все-таки больше связан как реализовать самостоятельно, а не воспользоваться готовыми классами(хотя лучше пользоваться стандартными классами). Это всего лишь учебный пример, потому что **Когда-то я также интересовался, как устроены умные указатели**.

```
template <class T>
class my_smart_ptr
{
private:
    int* count;
    T* obj;

public: 
    my_smart_ptr(T* v)
        : obj(v)
        , count(new int)
    {
        *count = 1;
        std::cout << "my_smart_ptr: increment counter" << std::endl;
    }
    ~my_smart_ptr()
    {
        --*count;
        std::cout << "my_smart_ptr: decrement counter" << std::endl;
        if (*count == 0)
        {
            delete obj;
            obj = nullptr;
            delete count;
            count = nullptr;
            std::cout << "my_smart_ptr deleted the object. The count equals 0" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    T* operator -> ()
    {
        return obj;
    }

    my_smart_ptr(const my_smart_ptr& other)
    {
        count = other.count;
        obj = other.obj;
        ++*count;
        std::cout << "my_smart_ptr: increment counter" << std::endl;
    }
    my_smart_ptr operator = (const my_smart_ptr& other)
    {
        my_smart_ptr<T> t(other);
        return t;       
    }
};

class example
{
private:
    int _a;
public:
    example(int a) : _a(a)
    {
        std::cout << "example: Call Constructor example" << std::endl;
    }
    ~example()
    {
        std::cout << "example: Call Destructor example: a=" << _a << std::endl;
    }

    void setA(int a) { _a = a; }

};


my_smart_ptr<example> foo()
{
    auto t = my_smart_ptr<example>(new example(10));
    int a = 10 + 5;
    a += 5;
    return t;
}

void foo2(my_smart_ptr<example> ex)
{
    ex->setA(5);
}

void foo3()
{
    my_smart_ptr<example> a = foo();
    foo2(a);
}

int main()
{
    foo3();
}
```

Это примерная реализация умных указателей. Суть работы их следующая. 
 Есть некий счетчик ссылок, который является указателем на int. Так как это указатель,  при копировании умного указателя счетчик копируется по ссылке(а не по значению), поэтому является общим для всех объектов. 
 
Пример класса является **непотокобезопасным**. Стандартные умные указатели являются потокобезопасными.

Comment: Тут же вновь реализация `shared_ptr`, практически дописанный кусок из ответа Harry.

Comment: `operator =` реализован неправильно: он ничего никуда не присваивает

Comment: старый вариант реализации метода my_smart_ptr<T> t = new my_smart_ptr<T>(other); вызовет конструктор копирования и присвоение произойдет, **почему вы считаете что присваивания не происходит?** Я согласен с тем, что в операторе присваивания лучше так не писать связи с тем, что мы формально можем уйти в рекурсию, но современные компиляторы вызовут конструктор копирования и проблем не вижу с кодом. В ответе явно изменил на вызов конструктора копирования(но фактически изменений в работе метода нет)

Answer (score 3):

Вот у Страуструпа есть подсчет ссылок при реализации класса String.

```
// String.h
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

#define DEBUG

#ifndef DEFINE_STRING
#define DEFINE_STRING

class String
{
    struct Srep
    {
        char* s;
        int n;
        int sz;

        Srep(int, const char*);
        ~Srep() { delete[] s; }

        Srep* GetOwnCopy();
        void Assign(int, const char*);

    private:
        Srep(const Srep&);
        Srep& operator=(const Srep&);
    };

    class Cref
    {
    public:
        inline Cref(String&, int);
        inline Cref(const Cref&);
        Cref();

        inline operator char() const;
        inline void operator=(char);

    private:
        String& s;
        int i;
    };

public:
    class Range { };

    inline String();
    inline String(const char*);
    String(const String&);

    ~String();

    String& operator=(const char*);
    String& operator=(const String&);

    inline void Check(int) const;

    inline char Read(int) const;
    inlinevoid Write(int, char);

    inline Cref operator[](int);
    inline char operator[](int) const;

    inline int Size() const;

private:
    Srep* rep;
};

inline String::String() : rep(new Srep(0, "") )
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline String::String()"
        << std::endl;
#endif
}
inline String::String(const char* p) :
    rep(new Srep(strlen(p), p) )
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline String::String(const char* p)"
        << std::endl;
#endif
}

inline void String::Check(int i) const
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline void String::Check(int i) const"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    if (i < 0 || rep->sz <= i) throw Range();
}

inline char String::Read(int i) const
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline char String::Read(int i) const"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    return rep->s[i];
}
inline void String::Write(int i, char c)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline void String::Write(int i, char c)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    rep = rep->GetOwnCopy();
    rep->s[i] = c;
}

inline String::Cref String::operator[](int i)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline String::Cref String::operator[](int i)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    Check(i);
    return Cref(*this, i);
}
inline char String::operator[](int i) const
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline char String::operator[](int i) const"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    Check(i);
    return rep->s[i];
}

inline int String::Size() const
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline int String::Size() const"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    return rep->sz;
}

inline String::Cref::Cref(String& ss, int ii) :
    s(ss), i(ii)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline String::Cref::Cref(String& ss, int ii)"
        << std::endl;
#endif
}
inline String::Cref::Cref(const Cref& r) :
    s(r.s), i(r.i)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline String::Cref::Cref(const Cref& r)"
        << std::endl;
#endif
}

inline String::Cref::operator char() const
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline String::Cref::operator char() const"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    s.Check(i);
    return s.Read(i);
}
inline void String::Cref::operator=(char c)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "inline void String::Cref::operator=(char c)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    s.Write(i, c);
}

#endif

// String.cpp

#include "String.h"

String::String(const String& r)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "String::String(const String& r)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    r.rep->n++;
    rep = r.rep;
}

String::~String()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "String::~String()"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    if (--rep->n == 0) delete rep;
}

String& String::operator=(const char* p)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "String& String::operator=(const char* p)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    if (rep->n == 1)
        rep->Assign(strlen(p), p);
    else
    {
        rep->n--;
        rep = new Srep(strlen(p), p);
    }

    return *this;
}
String& String::operator=(const String& r)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "String& String::operator=(const String& r)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    r.rep->n++;
    if (--rep->n == 0) delete rep;
    rep = r.rep;

    return *this;
}

String::Srep::Srep(int nsz, const char* p)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "String::Srep::Srep(int nsz, const char* p)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    n = 1;
    sz = nsz;
    s = new char[sz + 1];

    strcpy(s, p);
}
String::Srep* String::Srep::GetOwnCopy()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "String::Srep* String::Srep::GetOwnCopy()"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    if (n == 1) return this;
    n--;
    return new Srep(sz, s);
}
void String::Srep::Assign(int nsz, const char* p)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "void String::Srep::Assign(int nsz, const char* p)"
        << std::endl;
#endif

    if (nsz != sz)
    {
        delete[] s;
        sz = nsz;
        s = new char[sz + 1];
    }

    strcpy(s, p);
}
```